# How to set js-mode indent in Emacs >= 27.1

Tags: indentation, customize, tabs, js-mode

I have my tab width set to two spaces and this has worked fine for many years.  I have just upgraded to Emacs 27.1, and now `js-mode` is displaying tabs as three spaces wide, ignoring my preferred settings (which still apply to other modes, it's only `js-mode` that isn't respecting my preference.)

I can't work out how to make it go back to 2.  The tab width is still set to 2 in my `init.el` file, which hasn't changed during the Emacs upgrade.

If I press M-x and run `set-variable` then set `tab-width` to 2, the file goes back to the correct tab width.  But I can't work out how to make it apply to all files.  If I press `?` instead of `2` when setting `tab-width` then it tells me it is already set to 2 (which it is, in my `init.el`) however it seems I have to set it to 2 again, even though it's ready 2, for every `.js` file that I open.

How can I make it so that `js-mode` respects the tab widths I have set in `init.el`, as it did in earlier Emacs versions?

I've looked through all the options but I can only see two that are related to the tab width and they are already set to 2.

Is anyone else running Emacs 27.1 or newer?  Have you successfully changed the tab width for `.js` files?

Comment: I had a similar problem, except that I have my settings to 4, but it kept getting reset to 2. I used `debug-on-variable-change` on `tab-width` and found that it was invariably being set to `2` by `js-mode` because of http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/progmodes/js.el?h=emacs-27.1#n4614. Can you do the same and see what is changing it when you open a JS file? I ended up setting `c-default-style` to `user`, which for me defaults to `4`.

Comment: @Matt: Thanks for the suggestion!  Looks like the same issue although for me it appears to be trying to set it to `4`, then somehow ending up as 3 anyway.  My `c-default-style` is already set to my own custom one but strangely if I use `M-x set-variable c-default-style` it won't accept anything, including my custom one in init.el or `user`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding the following to my `init.el` file:

```
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook
  (function (lambda ()
    (setq indent-tabs-mode t
          tab-width 2))))
```

Seems it works by overriding the faulty default indent value every time you open a JS file.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like an issue with emacs, but I have not yet nailed it down. At any rate, it looks like the problem is the code in http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/progmodes/js.el?h=emacs-27.1#n4614 is running after all the other traditional packages (like editorconfig, etc) that I have used to set this value properly for different projects.

My current workaround is setting the following in my `.emacs` ..

```
(setq-default c-default-style '((js-mode . "user")
                                (java-mode . "java")
                                (awk-mode . "awk")
                                (other . "gnu")))
```

But this is a pure workaround (btw `user` just sets indent-size to 4). You would have to use another setting if you want something other than 4. It's not great because it is not project aware. Looking for a better solution in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

`js-mode`'s `js-indent-level` defaults to four spaces ( https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/5e5f5b28e92a3bb927bb03c783c426c6c3baeadc/lisp/progmodes/js.el#L434 ).

Adding the following to `init.el` sets tabs to two spaces in `js-mode` in emacs 30.0.50.

```
;; set js-mode indent level
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (setq js-indent-level 2)))
```

Comment: Use just `(lambda...)`, not `(function (lambda...))` in Elisp.